# What are the advantages / disadvantages of creating an own object for events to get it in codecompletion?

Tags: javascript, node.js, intellij-idea

In a nodejs application we have many events that will be emitted and catched. Events will be defined normally as simple strings like e. g. 'open'.
My idea is to create an own object for my events.

```
var event = {
  open: 'my-open',
  close: 'my-close'
};
module.exports = event;
```

The wanted benefits are:

- defined location where all events are defined
- code-completion within IDE (e. g. IntelliJ)

My question is if that is a good idea or if there are serious reasons to do not so?

**Update**
We've decided to use such an event object only within a module.
The benefits are:

- defined place of events
- possibility to structure the events
- renaming the events on a single place
- IDE support (code-completion, finding references)

Comment: I can't think of many (any, at the moment) downsides, it's a normal technique.

Comment: @adeneo Uhm, what does `^......` mean?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little two-sided on this:

- On the one hand I can see clear benefits, e.g. when using an IDE with auto-completion. Additionally, you have the advantage of having a single place where your events are defined. Also, this means that when e.g. you emit an event, you can clearly separate between your custom events and Node.js's own events, just by looking at the code. They are different types of events, and they just *look* different.
- On the other hand I think this overcomplicates things. Essentially, an event in Node.js is just a string. And your suggestions relies on object properties' names, which are - in the end - strings as well. There is no compiler support for this, because there is no compiler. So it doesn't matter if you mistype the actual event name or if you mistype the name of the event wrapping property.

In other words: If you do not use an IDE, it doesn't help at all. Instead, it forces you to collect all possible event names in a single place, which *will* make maintaining events difficult. Think of a high number of events over a long time: Which events can be safely removed without breaking code at a completely different place, maybe even in a different module? Or, as the event names may even be used in other modules, you have to search over all of your modules. In this case, I can - as well - just do a search for a string.

If I compare the benefits vs the risks, I'd probably go with event names as simple strings, as in Node.js itself.

Finally, there's one more thing I'd pay attention to: Sometimes it is necessary to create an event's name dynamically, by building up the event name string at runtime. As soon as you have something such as this, you end up with two different styles of emitting your custom events, and this breaks the rule that you have one consistent event style… so, if I consider this I'd be cautious even more.

And, (now really) finally, one last thing: Introducing such an object doesn't improve your code. It improves its compatibility with IDEs. And I doubt whether that's a solution, I'd rather consider it to be a workaround.